# sd_journal_print is not logging properly

Tags: linux, logging, systemd, systemd-journald

```
#include<systemd/sd-journal.h>

int main()
{
        sd_journal_print(LOG_WARNING, "Test message: Warning...");
        sd_journal_send("SD_JOURNAL_TEST=SEND Test message: Warning...", "PRIORITY=%i", LOG_WARNING, NULL);
}
```

Compiled with: `g++ sd-journal-test.cc -o sd-journal-test -lsystemd`

```
$journalctl --since "0.2 hours ago"
```

shows :

```
Jun 30 18:45:01 preetam-Precision-M4800 sd-journal-test[23739]: Test message: Warning...
```

sd_journal_print gave a log without line and other numbers and sd_journal_Send never logged.

Whats is the cause and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing invalid formatted arguments. `sd_journal_send` expects:

> The strings passed should be of the format
> "VARIABLE=value"

Correct use:

```c
    sd_journal_send("MESSAGE=Test message: Warning...", "SD_JOURNAL_TEST=SEND", "PRIORITY=%i", LOG_WARNING, NULL);
```

Comment: I thought  VARIABLE is whatever I want to provide ? Is it specifically 'MESSAGE' ?

Comment: man systemd.journal-fields(7): MESSAGE=
           The human-readable message string for this entry. This is supposed
           to be the primary text shown to the user. It is usually not
           translated (but might be in some cases), and is not supposed to be
           parsed for metadata.